# Different word other than "rude" for describing ellipsis usage

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, ellipses, pejorative-language

I am having trouble thinking of a word that can describe this type of situation.

Just as an example, over text, explaining something in detail to someone only to have them give a response such as, "Yeah... I see." It's not really "rude" but it almost feels as if they have more to say about it.

What would be a better way to describe this? Is there a word for it?

Comment: You have a selective view of the ellipses. Is is often used ... to represent a pause, as though the writer is thinking. When used in a quote, it shows that words have been omitted.

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but why not _elliptical_? http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/elliptical

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 3):

The ellipsis (...) as it is used nowadays has often struck me as being a sign of *laziness*... an unwillingness to finish a sentence. In other cases, it emphasizes the person's *indifference* and total lack of interest in the topic being discussed.

> - *Meh,... I guess so*
> - *Yeah, ... whatever*

In the OP's scenario, the message received:

> - *Yeah,... I see*

might express the texter's *[indecisiveness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indecisiveness)* or hesitancy, the number of dots acting as a visual indicator of their thinking in progress, in other words, the person is saying "I need more time to mull things over". Conversely, the three dots might represent the writer's decision *not* to express a direct opinion, otherwise known as [hedging](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hedging).  The ellipsis could also be hinting a lukewarm **disagreement**, especially true if it is the only response given to a detailed proposal. If, however, the response was immediate it might be interpreted as a sign of politeness, the texter/sender acknowledging they have read the message and the ellipsis implies the promise of a more detailed and thoughtful reply in the not too distant future... but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems like the person is being *dismissive.* They are not taking the time to consider your well-reasoned explanation.

[*Dismissive* is defined as:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dismissive)

> reacting to something in a way that shows you do not think it is worth paying attention to

Answer (score 0):

[Oblique](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oblique)?

The speaker has left you with the impression that something is unsaid.